# LCD driver board M.NT68676.2 issue: Screen compressed, fills only part of display

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, hdmi, monitor, lvds

I am trying to build a portable Raspberry Pi/Retropie system with an LCD screen I got from my old laptop (the idea is to have a portable gaming console to be used in a car). To drive the screen, I am using a M.NT68676.2 monitor control board ([datasheet](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/M.NT68676.2A.html)) i got from ebay.

When I connect board and screen to my computer, the desktop shows up but the picture is compressed and fills only about three fourths of the screen horizontally from the left (the rest is black). Vertically, there is no compression and the lower end of the desktop falls outside the screen. When I access the on-screen menu provided by the board, it gives me the correct resolution I have set although that obviously isn't the case.

I have been googling for days now but found not even a description of the problem. The issue remains irrespective of machine used (Pi, two laptops), connection used (HDMI and VGA), operating system (Windows, Ubuntu) and all other settings I know of (e.g. framebuffer in Linux). Connections have been checked about a hundred times. I am therefore totally at a loss.

According to the sticker on the back, the LCD I am using is an LG/Philips LP154W01(TL)(AE) and the M.NT68676.2 has been flashed accordingly by the retailer (who suspects a fail in the LCD although from his mails I think he just doesn't know what to do).

Has anyone had similar experiences? Are there any ideas what could cause the issue? The only possible hint that I have found so far is that the screen board itself states "Desc: LP154W01-TLA8-E22" which to me seems to refer to a different model number than given on the back of the LCD itsef.

Comment: Hi there Thomas. Did you find any solution to your problem?? I'm having a similar problem, which I explain here: http://superuser.com/questions/1171031/lcd-controller-board-showing-image-four-times and I don't know what to do...

Comment: try uncommenting #hdmi_force_hotplug=1 in /boot/config.txt
that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to reflash exact resolution firmware by rt809f programmer. I also got 1280x800 board resolution but I needed 1200x800 as per my LCD. So my picture was slightly bigger with height of same as of screen but width was slightly bigger.so some portion were cutting. In your case low resolution firmware may have burned.just download the firmware file of your board and flash it either hex or bin file. You will be good to go